# which answer is correct and why? $\arcsin \left(\sin\frac{11\pi}{4}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of  $\arcsin\left(\sin\dfrac{11\pi}4\right)$

I'm confused if the answer should be $\dfrac{\pi}4$ or $\dfrac{3\pi}4$.

my calculator says it's $\dfrac{\pi}4$ however I don't understand why that is correct? Is that because of the range?

Comment: It is essentially due to the range. While $\sin(\pi/4) = \sin(3\pi/4)$, $\arcsin$ is by definition the inverse of the sine function restricted to the interval $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, and thus has range $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.

Answer (score 1):

The range of the arcsine function is $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.  Thus,

$$\arcsin\left[\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{4}\right)\right] \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$

Since

\begin{align*}
\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{4}\right) & = \sin\left(2\pi + \frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\\
                                 & = \sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\\
                                 & = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)
\end{align*}

we may conclude that

$$\arcsin\left[\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{4}\right)\right] = \arcsin\left[\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right] = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(11\pi/4) = \sin(2\pi+3\pi/4) = \sin(3\pi/4) = \sin(\pi/4) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Rightarrow \text{arcsin(sin} (11\pi/4)) = \text{arcsin}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \pi/4$, since $\text{arcsin}(x) \in \left[-\pi/2,\pi/2\right]$.